# Parse error in PHP MySQL connect

Tags: php, mysql

It says on the error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tola\showrep.php on line 8, i dont know what to do please help.

```
<?php
        include('../connection.php');

        $id =$_REQUEST['id'];

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE id = '$id'")

        header("Location: filter.php"); 
        mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: "Parse error" is just another way to say "syntax error". (Hint: in PHP you need to finish statements with `;`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a minor issue you are missing a semicolon in the following line:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE id = '$id'");
```

However it is a **CRITICALLY** bad practice to pass request variables to SQL query, it makes your code vulnerable and open to SQL Injection, XSS and many other security risks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `;` at the end of `mysql_query(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

for evading the sql inyection you can use this:

```
$id =$_REQUEST['id'];
$id=stripslashes($id)
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE id = '$id'");
```

see you :D

Comment: They've called from year 2000, they want their stripslashes back ;-)

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use prepared statements with `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.